# ImageReader setOnImageAvailableListener never working

Tags: java, android, image, camera, android-camera2

I have made a lot of researches about my problem but none helped me to make my code run, the preview of my camera 2 api is working and displayed on a surfaceview, but when I want to save the picture by a button clique, the ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener never works.

```
android.util.Size[] jpegSizes = null;
                jpegSizes = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                int width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                int height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
                ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
                List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(1);
                outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
                outputSurfaces.add(mCameraSurface_1);
                final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = 
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
                reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mHandler);
```

and I use this code to read the imageavailable, the message log "success" is never showed

```
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Log.v(TAG,"success" );
        
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            save(bytes);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not build the captureBuilder in order to get a CaptureRequest. You can use a CameraCaptureSession and send the captureBuilder.build() in the capture method for the session. Please see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder